# 403 forbidden due to .htaccess?

Tags: htaccess

I have this 403 forbidden issue that i can't tell what's causing it.
At this moment, i've already talked with theme support, wich advised me to talk with host support, wich i've done it already, they identified the issue after following the steps i told. They suggested then to check either with cloudflare support or w3tc, cause after running Firebug's "NET" the following info was:

```
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Server: cloudflare-nginx
Date: Wed, 25 Sep 2013 10:46:34 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
X-Pingback: http://findout-macau.com/xmlrpc.php
Expires: Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
Pragma: no-cache
X-Powered-By: W3 Total Cache/0.9.3
X-W3TC-Minify: On
Link: <http://wp.me/3UMOt>; rel=shortlink
Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
CF-RAY: b3721978b0506dc
Content-Encoding: gzip
```

I've checked with cloudflare, and they let me know that usually this kinda of issue has to do with:

```
1. Permission rules you have set or an error in the .htaccess rules you have set.
2. Mod_security rules.
3. IP Deny rules
```

Nevertheless i've my .htaccess content below:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/wp-content/uploads/(.*)$ http://images.findout-macau.com/$1

# BEGIN W3TC Browser Cache
<IfModule mod_mime.c>
AddType text/css .css
AddType text/x-component .htc
AddType application/x-javascript .js
AddType application/javascript .js2
AddType text/javascript .js3
AddType text/x-js .js4
AddType text/html .html .htm
AddType text/richtext .rtf .rtx
AddType image/svg+xml .svg .svgz
AddType text/plain .txt
AddType text/xsd .xsd
AddType text/xsl .xsl
AddType text/xml .xml
AddType video/asf .asf .asx .wax .wmv .wmx
AddType video/avi .avi
AddType image/bmp .bmp
AddType application/java .class
AddType video/divx .divx
AddType application/msword .doc .docx
AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject .eot
AddType application/x-msdownload .exe
AddType image/gif .gif
AddType application/x-gzip .gz .gzip
AddType image/x-icon .ico
AddType image/jpeg .jpg .jpeg .jpe
AddType application/json .json
AddType application/vnd.ms-access .mdb
AddType audio/midi .mid .midi
AddType video/quicktime .mov .qt
AddType audio/mpeg .mp3 .m4a
AddType video/mp4 .mp4 .m4v
AddType video/mpeg .mpeg .mpg .mpe
AddType application/vnd.ms-project .mpp
AddType application/x-font-otf .otf
AddType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.database .odb
AddType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.chart .odc
AddType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.formula .odf
AddType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.graphics .odg
AddType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation .odp
AddType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet .ods
AddType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text .odt
AddType audio/ogg .ogg
AddType application/pdf .pdf
AddType image/png .png
AddType application/vnd.ms-powerpoint .pot .pps .ppt .pptx
AddType audio/x-realaudio .ra .ram
AddType application/x-shockwave-flash .swf
AddType application/x-tar .tar
AddType image/tiff .tif .tiff
AddType application/x-font-ttf .ttf .ttc
AddType audio/wav .wav
AddType audio/wma .wma
AddType application/vnd.ms-write .wri
AddType application/vnd.ms-excel .xla .xls .xlsx .xlt .xlw
AddType application/zip .zip
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType text/css A31536000
ExpiresByType text/x-component A31536000
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript A31536000
ExpiresByType application/javascript A31536000
ExpiresByType text/javascript A31536000
ExpiresByType text/x-js A31536000
ExpiresByType text/html A3600
ExpiresByType text/richtext A3600
ExpiresByType image/svg+xml A3600
ExpiresByType text/plain A3600
ExpiresByType text/xsd A3600
ExpiresByType text/xsl A3600
ExpiresByType text/xml A3600
ExpiresByType video/asf A31536000
ExpiresByType video/avi A31536000
ExpiresByType image/bmp A31536000
ExpiresByType application/java A31536000
ExpiresByType video/divx A31536000
ExpiresByType application/msword A31536000
ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject A31536000
ExpiresByType application/x-msdownload A31536000
ExpiresByType image/gif A31536000
ExpiresByType application/x-gzip A31536000
ExpiresByType image/x-icon A31536000
ExpiresByType image/jpeg A31536000
ExpiresByType application/json A31536000
ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-access A31536000
ExpiresByType audio/midi A31536000
ExpiresByType video/quicktime A31536000
ExpiresByType audio/mpeg A31536000
ExpiresByType video/mp4 A31536000
ExpiresByType video/mpeg A31536000
ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-project A31536000
ExpiresByType application/x-font-otf A31536000
ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.database A31536000
ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.chart A31536000
ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.formula A31536000
ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.graphics A31536000
ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation A31536000
ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet A31536000
ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text A31536000
ExpiresByType audio/ogg A31536000
ExpiresByType application/pdf A31536000
ExpiresByType image/png A31536000
ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-powerpoint A31536000
ExpiresByType audio/x-realaudio A31536000
ExpiresByType image/svg+xml A31536000
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash A31536000
ExpiresByType application/x-tar A31536000
ExpiresByType image/tiff A31536000
ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf A31536000
ExpiresByType audio/wav A31536000
ExpiresByType audio/wma A31536000
ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-write A31536000
ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-excel A31536000
ExpiresByType application/zip A31536000
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
</IfModule>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css text/x-component application/x-javascript application/javascript text/javascript text/x-js text/html text/richtext image/svg+xml text/plain text/xsd text/xsl text/xml image/x-icon application/json
<IfModule mod_mime.c>
    # DEFLATE by extension
    AddOutputFilter DEFLATE js css htm html xml
</IfModule>
</IfModule>
<FilesMatch "\.(css|htc|js|js2|js3|js4|CSS|HTC|JS|JS2|JS3|JS4)$">
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Pragma "public"
    Header append Cache-Control "public"
     Header unset Set-Cookie
     Header set X-Powered-By "W3 Total Cache/0.9.3"
 </IfModule>
 </FilesMatch>
 <FilesMatch  "\.(html|htm|rtf|rtx|svg|svgz|txt|xsd|xsl|xml|HTML|HTM|RTF|RTX|SVG|SVGZ|TXT|XSD|XSL|XML)$">
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Pragma "public"
    Header append Cache-Control "public"
     Header set X-Powered-By "W3 Total Cache/0.9.3"
 </IfModule>
 </FilesMatch>
 <FilesMatch "\.(asf|asx|wax|wmv|wmx|avi|bmp|class|divx|doc|docx|eot|exe|gif|gz|gzip|ico|jpg|jpeg|jpe|json|mdb|mid|midi|mov|qt|mp3|m4a|mp4|m4v|mpeg|mpg|mpe|mpp|otf|odb|odc|odf|odg|odp|ods|odt|ogg|pdf|png|pot|pps|ppt|pptx|ra|ram|svg|svgz|swf|tar|tif|tiff|ttf|ttc|wav|wma|wri|xla|xls|xlsx|xlt|xlw|zip|ASF|ASX|WAX|WMV|WMX|AVI|BMP|CLASS|DIVX|DOC|DOCX|EOT|EXE|GIF|GZ|GZIP|ICO|JPG|JPEG|JPE|JSON|MDB|MID|MIDI|MOV|QT|MP3|M4A|MP4|M4V|MPEG|MPG|MPE|MPP|OTF|ODB|ODC|ODF|ODG|ODP|ODS|ODT|OGG|PDF|PNG|POT|PPS|PPT|PPTX|RA|RAM|SVG|SVGZ|SWF|TAR|TIF|TIFF|TTF|TTC|WAV|WMA|WRI|XLA|XLS|XLSX|XLT|XLW|ZIP)$">
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Pragma "public"
    Header append Cache-Control "public"
     Header unset Set-Cookie
     Header set X-Powered-By "W3 Total Cache/0.9.3"
 </IfModule>
 </FilesMatch>
 # END W3TC Browser Cache
 # BEGIN W3TC Page Cache core
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteRule .* - [E=W3TC_SSL:_ssl]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =443
RewriteRule .* - [E=W3TC_SSL:_ssl]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Encoding} gzip
RewriteRule .* - [E=W3TC_ENC:_gzip]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !=POST
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =""
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \/$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !(comment_author|wp\-postpass|w3tc_logged_out|wordpress_logged_in|wptouch_switch_toggle) [NC]
RewriteCond "%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wp-content/cache/page_enhanced/%{HTTP_HOST}/%{REQUEST_URI}/_index%{ENV:W3TC_SSL}.html%{ENV:W3TC_ENC}" -f
RewriteRule .* "/wp-content/cache/page_enhanced/%{HTTP_HOST}/%{REQUEST_URI}/_index%{ENV:W3TC_SSL}.html%{ENV:W3TC_ENC}" [L]
</IfModule>
# END W3TC Page Cache core
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

What i'ld like to know is some tip on how to solve this?
Does someone believes to know how to get through this?

Comment: I can access to http://wp.me/3UMOt without any problem and it returns 200 status code, which is just fine.

Comment: Indeed, if you access directly that page, it shows no issues. But if you proceed some few steps before, will encounter that 403 forbidden issue. The steps regards, signing up, enter a (place) post, hit upgrade listing at the picture's right, choose VIP, check NO business owner and at last at the bottom check accept terms and hit review listing... this is were the 403 issue happens, when it should show a post preview and forward for paypal payment page. This is messing my head up...

Comment: You should update your questions including those "steps", You should provide a demo user account also to let us log in withour create a user account. Anyway, I think your problem can be related with SSL and it is not reltaed with Wordpress itself.

Comment: the demo user is:
demo@findout-macau.com
demo2013
@cybnet The steps are: sign in at [link](http://findout-macau.com) choose a place that can be this one [link](http://findout-macau.com/city/rio-hotel/) hit **upgrade listing** at pictures's right box select _VIP Package_ select _no_ to business owner, and at the bottom, check _accept terms_ and finally hit **review listing** the following page is where you can find the 403 issue, confirmed by firebug NET tab on that page.
If it regards SSL, do you suggest any solution for me to go for it?
Many thanks

Comment: In this [link](http://findout-macau.com/city/rio-hotel/) there is no "Upgrade listing" where I can click. But I've followed all steps in [this one](http://findout-macau.com/city/tim-test/) and I don't get a 403 status code, I get 200 instead. So I don't see any problem at all.

Comment: @cybnet In fact  i can also manage to upgrade in that one that i created recently, not in any other previously created, as suc
h this one [link](http://findout-macau.com/city/grand-lisboa/). The reason you didn't find **upgrade listing** button early was my mistake. Need to be _business owner_ first and then you're able to upgrade.

Comment: @cybnet you can also find the issue i'm talking about, in that same TIM TEST [link](http://findout-macau.com/city/tim-test/) but instead of making all those steps, just try to upload an image at the bottom trhough the _select file_ option.